# javaMail not working with OAuth gmail send email

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, gmail, google-oauth, jakarta-mail

javaMail: send mail using google oauth caused javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true"); // required for Gmail
props.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, xyz@gmail.com, oauth_access_token);
```

The oauth access token is valid, just refreshed, about 20 seconds before running the code.

Error:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s136sm158338qka.106 - gsmtp

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:965)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:876)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:780)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
```

From the logging, it seems that auth is using username/password, not OAUTH. guide: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2

Logging:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP s136sm158338qka.106 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=xyz@gmail.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes across this page: JavaMail *does* work with Gmail OAuth2 authentication. The following is how it works on my Kotlin code base:

1. The props needed for [`Session`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Session.html) is shown below (it's in yaml format, but you get the idea):

```yaml
javamail:
  config:
    "mail.smtp.host": smtp.gmail.com
    "mail.smtp.port": 587
    "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": true
    "mail.smtp.starttls.required": true
    "mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms": XOAUTH2
```

2. When constructing an email (multi-part or not), the enclosing mime message must be bound to a `Session` that has all the above props. This can be easily missed when using a class from a library to construct an email (like  [`SimpleEmail`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/mail/SimpleEmail.html)):

```kotlin
val session = Session.getInstance(javamail.config().toProperties())

val email = SimpleEmail().apply {
    setMailSession(session) // do not forget this line
    setCharset("utf-8")
    setFrom(credInfo.email())
    addTo("someone@somewhere.com")
    setSubject("Test email")
    setMsg("This is the test.")

    buildMimeMessage()
}
```

3. Call a static method [`Transport.send(msg, username, password)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), where `username` is your email, and `password` is your fresh access-token. There's no need to create an instance of `Transport`, nor a need to call `transport.connect()`:

```kotlin
Transport.send(email.mimeMessage, gmail, accessToken)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to disable the plain authentication to force Jakarta Mail to use XOAUTH2.

props.put("mail.smtp.auth.plain.disable", "true");

Comment: already specified mechanisms: props.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2"); I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Trying the following code:

```
        Properties props = new Properties()
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com")
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587")
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true")
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true")
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2")
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth.login.disable", "true")
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth.plain.disable", "true")
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth.ntlm.disable", "true")
            props.put("mail.debug", "true")
            props.put("mail.debug.auth", "true")
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props)
            String emptyPassword = ""
            final URLName unusedUrlName = null
            SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName)
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", googleEmail, googleAccessToken)\
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart()
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart()
            def from = googleEmail
            def to = "test@test.com"
            def subj = "TestOath2Gmail"
            def body = "TTT"
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(googleEmail))
            message.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to))
            Date sentDate = new Date()
            message.setSentDate(sentDate)
            message.setSubject(subj)
            messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html")
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart)
            message.setContent(multipart)
            transport.send(message)
```

Getting error:
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism XOAUTH2
AUTH XOAUTH2
235 2.7.0 Accepted
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=username, password=

Comment: Yes. The code is working but I am getting the error that I described.

Comment: It still asked for username and password, OAUTH ignored. Could not find a working example online.

Comment: The same problem, nothing work with gmail oauth2.

Comment: Java mail should have a working example for oauth before it is released.